# What happened to the Rendlesham Forest Bird climbing frame?

Tags: uk, walking, children

We're semi-frequent visitors to [Rendlesham Forest](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@52.0811424,1.4357633,5445m/data=!3m1!1e3), in Suffolk, England.  A few years ago (probably 2008-2009), whilst walking not too far from the main car park we came across a large wooden structure roughly resembling a bird.  You could climb up its back, go inside it and it had a firemans pole at one end.  It wasn't anywhere near or part of the "UFO" trail and the associated games/climbing structures that are to the north west of the car park, I feel it was more to the south / south west amongst the red and blue walking trails.

On more recent trips within the last couple of years, we've been unable to find it again - despite being pretty sure we're back in the right area, there is no sign of it.  Does anyone know if anything has happened to it, and if it's still there, a sure fire way to find it on a visit?

There are posts, along with the blue/red coloured walking trails, that seem to indicate "bird this way", but we followed those on a trip last year without finding it, and walking a lot further and in a different direction to what we remembered, so I'm almost sure that those posts are directing you to something else - there are a couple of RSPB sites nearby for instance.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the council?

Comment: @Liam No - that's a good suggestion though.  Also the Forestry Commission (it's their site).  I will do so, and update back here if I find anything out!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently it was removed due to lack of funding for repairs. [Here's](http://saveourwoods.co.uk/get-involved/local-campaigns/forest-users-tell-the-government-fund-and-run-our-forests-properly/) a link to an article about it. [Here's](https://www.flickr.com/photos/bobby45/1304429936/) a link to a picture for the curious. Too bad.

Comment: Thanks - I'd not been able to find any info, but that article confirms my suspicions that it couldn't be maintained.  Shame, since there's a bunch of newer stuff (the UFO trail I mentioned) that's been put in so they're not completely without funds.  FWIW, I sent an email to the address listed on the Forestry Commission website for Rendlesham, if they reply with any other "official" info, I'll update back.

Answer (score 4):

After the prompt by [Liam](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7873/what-happened-to-the-rendlesham-forest-bird-climbing-frame/7890#comment16667_7873) in the comments, I got in touch with the Forestry Commission via their website - it seems they list an email contact for each site.

I received the following reply, confirming [Joe's answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/7888/5413):

> The Nightjar (wooden bird) had been repaired over many years.  However, the foundations had begun to rot beyond repair; it was with some sadness that we dismantled it.
>
> It used to be on the 'blue' walking trail - the site is easy to find as it has two benches on the edge of a clearing.  In addition the years of woodchip has created something of a dome.